# Interpretation of SML (Security Market Line) parameters

Tags: portfolio-optimization, capm, market-model

I estimated a SML in terms of excess returns and I get the following parameters:

$\gamma_0=0.0286$

$\gamma_1=0.0263$

How can i give an economic interpretation of these two values? How they shape my model?

Note: In our assignment we have to deal with the following formula:

$$ R_i - R_f = \gamma_0 + \beta_i(\gamma_1)$$

$\gamma_1$ is excess return of the market (Rm-Rf) that is multiplied by the Beta of the stock, to which is added $\gamma_0$ to find the excess return on the stock.

Comment: it's a bit different. In our assignment we have to deal with the following formula: Ri - Rf = gamma0 + Beta(gamma1). So gamma0 is exactly the classic alpha (idiosyncratic risk) but gamma1 is excess return of the market (Rm-Rf) that multiplies the classic beta(systematic risk)

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you. I edited the question accordingly. Hope it is OK with you.

Comment: Absolutely, thank you @noob2